# CamelContext: Failed create route contain quartz when database is unreachable

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, apache-karaf, postgresql-9.4

My bundle installed into karaf container 4.0.7, that use camel-quartz22.17.3
In camelContext I have many routes such as "myRoute", it call a job quatrz (using camel-quartz2) configured in postgresql database:

```
<camelContext id="myCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <route id="myRoute">
            <from
                uri="quartz2://statGroup/startupTimer?trigger.repeatInterval=1&amp;trigger.repeatCount=0" />
            <bean ref="myProcessor" method="myMethod" />
        </route>

 </camelContext>
```

My issue is when I try to starting the karaf container and postgresql is stopped, I have the log problem below and the camelContext "myCamelContext" will be shutdown.

It's possible to create route that call camel-quartz but the database is unreachable ?

```
2016-10-14 17:21:40,201 | ERROR | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintCamelContext            | 80 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.17.3 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(statisticsContext) due Failed to create route myRoute: Route(myRoute)[[From[quartz2://stat... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz2://statGroup/startupTimer?trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.repeatInterval=1 due to: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'statQuartzDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'osgi:service/statQuartzDS' java.sql.SQLException: Unable to acquire a new connection from the pool
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route myRoute: Route(myRoute)[[From[quartz2://stat... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz2://statGroup/startupTimer?trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.repeatInterval=1 due to: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'statQuartzDS': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'osgi:service/statQuartzDS' java.sql.SQLException: Unable to acquire a new connection from the pool
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3301)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3024)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2854)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2873)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2819)[83:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.start(BlueprintCamelContext.java:180)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.maybeStart(BlueprintCamelContext.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.serviceChanged(BlueprintCamelContext.java:150)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:991)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:839)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:546)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4557)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3549)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:348)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.init(BlueprintCamelContext.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[12:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:980)[12:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:736)[12:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:848)[12:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811)[12:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[12:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_101]
```

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements for using quartz in the first place? Have you considered using `timer` component instead? Also could you please format your question by using three backticks to highlight the code block?

Comment: Yes i have a specific requirement for using quartz

Comment: I meant which particular feature of quartz do you need here?

Comment: perhaps, is not required to use quartz here, but i have others routes that require quartz. Systematically i have the same problem when quartz call job stored in database

Comment: why do you need quartz in those other routes? I'm asking to understand what do you use from it. E.g. if you don't care about using it's persistence mechanisms you can just switch to `RAMJobStore`

Comment: In fact, persistence mechanisms is a principal requirement because i have many nodes karaf that can be contains my bundle, so we should have centralized jobStore

Comment: How your app will be handling the absence of the db if it's necessary?

Comment: Well if the database is unreachable, what behavior do you expect? Camel will complain that the data source is not available.

Comment: when the database is unreachable i want that camel not fail route creation